# Code inside nested If statements

Tags: c++

is there be any performance effect on "Lines of code" running inside nested ifs?

```
if (condition_1)
{
   if (condition_2)
   {
      if (condition_n)
      {
          /* Lines of code */
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be a performance effect. Any decent compiler should easily be able to cope with that and optimize it correctly. The biggest problem with your code is not the performance but the readability.

By the way, you could easily rewrite it to the following more readable code:

```
if (condition_1 &&
    condition_2 &&
    ...etc...)
{
     /* Lines of code */
}
```

Comment: unless there's code right after the block of `condition_2` or `condition_n`, in which case your code is not equivalent to the OP's code.

Comment: @willhelmtell: Yeah if the OPs actual code is different from what he posted then of course my answer won't work. I guess I can't argue with that. :)